# Should you accept the first correct response or the one with the most detail

Tags: discussion

I just recently posted a question where I quickly received two correct responses.  The first was posted a few minutes after I asked my question, and the second about four minutes later.

The first answer while correct, was terse. The second answer had additional elaboration that provided context.  I am satisfied with the first answer, but the second provided additional information that I didn't know (which was not necessary for the solution, but interesting nonetheless).

My question: Is it more appropriate to accept the first correct answer, or the one that took additional work (and time) to provide more detail?

Comment: You decide.  It is completely up to you.  Which did you find more useful?  Which person do you want to reward the 15 rep too?

Comment: Keep in mind that the accepted answer may get more visibility, especially from people who do not visit the site often. So choosing a detailed answer rather than the first correct one is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both answers being equally correct, I would consider the one with details and explanation "more correct" and accept that one, provided the details and explanation are accurate and correct.

The more complete answer that explains *The Why* behind the problem and solution hopefully encourages people reading it to learn more about their systems, and that's something we as a community heartily encourage :-)

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the proper way to look at it.  I ended up choosing the first answer (you know the question I'm referring to), but was surprised that I was torn about choosing an answer.  I ended up giving the second answer an upvote so their effort wasn't in vain.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely accept the answer that is the most helpful, which is always the one with the most relevant detail.

Answer (score 5):

Accepting answers, like voting, tends to be a somewhat personal decision. Not everyone is going to agree with your choice but that doesn't mean that choice is either right or wrong.

I used to simply accept the first answer but now tend to wait a little longer. It's not at all uncommon to receive multiple correct answers and these days I prefer to accept an answer for more reasons that just being correct. Some people put a lot of effort into their answers and I feel that in many cases those should receive the rep.